# insert custom element inside wordpress menu

Tags: wordpress

I need to insert empty `<li>` element just after first menu item so I can make use of borders and get desired effect.
How is this done in Wordpress?
Just to make sure it is all clear.. this is current menu structure that Wordpress generates:

```
<ul>
 <li><a href='#'>item1</a></li>
 <li><a href='#'>item2</a></li>
 ...
</ul>
```

What I need is:

```
<ul>
 <li><a href='#'>item1</a></li>
 <li class='empty-item'></li>
 <li><a href='#'>item2</a></li>
 ...
</ul>
```

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

If your theme uses the WP Menu's you can go to Appearance>Menu's and add a "custom menu item". Just place a # for the URL and name it whatever you want. Click and to place it in the menu items listed and drag it just below the top menu item.

Comment: The thing is that you have to name it otherwise it wont insert it and I need it to be empty so I can make use of empty-item border tricks. Anyways I made use of `wp_get_nav_menu_items()`. Thanks ;)